# LaunchedEffect executing on configuration change even though rememberUpdatedState has not changed

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

If I'm understanding the documentation correctly a LaunchedEffect should not run again if the rememberUpdatedState has not changed.

If I run something like this code below then it's not working as expected and the value is getting updated again on rotation.

Without the LaunchedEffect the rememberSaveable is remembered on config change and the text in the input is correct (if I type something it's still there). This leads me to believe that the rememberUpdatedState should also not have changed but yet it gets triggered. Why?

What am I doing wrong or is this a bug? Alternatively is there a better way to do this?

Thanks :)

```
@Composable
fun ThingView(
    thingViewModel: ThingViewModel,
    id: String?
) {
    var thingName by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
    LaunchedEffect(rememberUpdatedState(newValue = thingName)) {
        scope.launch {
            id?.let {
                val thing = thingViewModel.getThing(id)
                thingName = thing.name
            }
        }
    }
    
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = thingName,
        onValueChange = { thingName = it },
        label = { Text("Name") }
    )
}
```

**Edit:**

To clarify, the goal is to allow the user enter text in a textField and not have that text cleared on rotation. That would be super annoying for a user and probably not what they expect.

Comment: were you able to find any solution?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. I haven't really been looking at this since I posted but I'll eventually circle back to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is that the `LaunchedEffect` state gets cleared on rotation when the configuration changes.  Consequently I don't think there is any value that you can provide as a key to keep it from running.

There are two options that come to mind. In the style of your original code, you might consider only declaring the `LaunchedEffect` when you determine the state has changed.  For example, you might maintain the last seen `id` in a saveable, say `lastId`, and test for changes on entry.  It requires you have a sentinel value for `lastId` initially of course.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ThingView(
    thingViewModel: ThingViewModel,
    id: String?
) {
    var thingName by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var lastId: String? by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(null) }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    if (lastId != id) {
        lastId = id
        LaunchedEffect(id) {
            scope.launch {
                id?.let {
                    val thing = thingViewModel.getThing(id)
                    thingName = thing.name
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = thingName,
        onValueChange = { thingName = it },
        label = { Text("Name") }
    )
}
```

Another option that might be more traditional is to use the `ViewModel` to persist the state across configuration changes.  You might update the ViewModel on each `onValueChange` and have the `ViewModel` provide the current value back to the `OutlinedTextField`.  In this style you might not need the effect or the coroutine.

Just a last word regarding my understanding about `rememberUpdatedState`.  I believe it is typically intended to allow a *long-lived* coroutine or callback to reference the current value of a variable in the composable scope without requiring that the coroutine or callback be recreated on each state change. The closure seems to be scoped to the effect and it capture the values at the time of creation.  I am still trying to understand it better.

Comment: Hey I just added an "edit" to clarify what I was trying to do. It's simply to stop the text in a textField from getting cleared on rotation. Are you able to get that to work? I'm actually using the id in LaunchedEffect. That was just some test code to figure out why LaunchedEffect is being run on rotation. The id has not changed.

Comment: @MichaelVescovo I adjusted the reply to provide a couple of options to avoid reinitializing the text on rotation.

Comment: If I declare the id locally like you did with lastId and rememberSavable that works. It seems you can't pass in a value to the LaunchedEffect from the constructor. I think I'm also confused now with rememberUpdateState and this was so long ago I'm wondering if I remember what else I was trying to do. Anyway I think that solves my issue for now. Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to hear it worked.  Please don't take away the message that constructor values cannot be used in a LaunchedEffect.  One can definitely pass a constructor value into a LaunchedEffect.

Comment: I think the lesson here is that firstly, I can't remember what I was trying to do with `rememberUpdatedState` since it was so long ago! I think it was for the text to stay there so let's go with that. Secondly you don't need it for this usecase. Also, if you pass in a constructor value into the LaunchedEffect, then even if that value doesn't change, the LaunchedEffect will re-run on rotation. If that's not what you want then take a copy of the value and store it in a `rememberSavable`.